# What's the best test to detect a disproportionate impact?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance, social-science

I work for a public agency and want to determine if we are serving neighborhoods equally regardless of their socioeconomic status.

We have a number of facilities, each in a different neighborhood. We are particularly interested in one metric of these facilities, which is expressed as a percentage. The actual metric doesn’t matter here, so let’s call it “percentage awesome.” Facility A might be 28% awesome, Facility B is 56% awesome, etc. Each facility has a different service area.

For each facility I’ve got data on the percentage of people in the service area who are below a certain income threshold.

Basically, I want to know if the facility’s percentage awesome has any relationship to the percentage of low-income people there. If it does, it could signal an equity issue and something we need to look into and fix.

I am wondering what the best test to perform is. If I did an ANOVA, I think I’d have to coerce the percentages of low-income people into bins, which I could do but I fear could obscure some of the results. Also, we’re only talking about 40 facilities in total here, so the bins would be quite small.

I was thinking of calculating the correlation coefficient, but I’m not sure how I would decide that a given correlation coefficient does or does not signal to us that poor neighborhoods are getting worse service. I don’t think doing a hypothesis test on the correlation coefficient would make sense because it’s not sample data; I am testing 100% of our facilities.

Is there another test that would be better, or am I missing something here? How do I translate this data into "yes there is a disproportionate impact" or "there is no evidence of a disproportionate impact?"

Comment: You can regress the outcome on percent lower income. There will be endogeneity issues, of course. For instance, what if the mere fact that low income are present makes this facility less awesome? This wouldn’t be because you don’t serve equally but maybe low income people behave differently. Maybe they tend to borrow toilet paper more often so you are more likely to experience toilet paperlessness in these facilities despite supplying equal amount of this critical resource to all locations

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think you are suggesting doing a regression of percent lower income and percent awesome. My big question though is at what r-squared value can I conclude that there is or isn't a disparity?

Comment: As for your concern about endogeneity - that's not a concern in this context, but thanks for bringing it up. The percent awesome measures something fixed about the facility that a user wouldn't be able to influence.

Comment: you can look at p-value of the coefficient instead of R-squared. the example I gave you is just one way endogeneity creeps in to your analysis, I have no doubt that it will find other avenues. other issues that you need to deal with is ceteris paribus: how do you know that it is only income that affects the score? you likely in need to control for other factors.

Comment: Thanks Aksakal. I will look into that. I am not trying to say that income affects the percent awesome score. What I'm trying to say is whether people in low-income neighborhoods are getting worse service or not (say, because of unconscious bias that creeped in when facilities were being designed). I know there are many things besides income that could correlate with this but for this analysis it is one of my key focuses. I'm also going to look at percent people of color in the neighborhood. Does that make sense?